# How to Uninstall DLC in The Last of Us

Tags: ps3, the-last-of-us

I have finished the "Left Behind" DLC episode and would like to uninstall it to get some space on my hard drive. I would, however, like to keep the "Abandoned Territories" multiplayer DLC and the base game files.

In the game files folder there is a tab called "Additional Content", but I suspect this includes everything, like the special edition content, the multiplayer DLC and "Left Behind".

Is there any way to uninstall DLC seperately? And if there is not, can I safely delete the "Additional Content" tab and re-install the other DLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to remove the "additional content" & redownload your requested DLC. It shouldn't pose any problem, and if it does, just delete all game content and download the DLC again. You'll need to download the patch again, though.